# the analog to geodesic problem but with the area ?? for a variational problem

Tags: differential-geometry

so we have that if we minimize the functional

$$ S= \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{g_{a,b}\dot x_{a}\dot x_{b}}$$

then the Euler Lagrange equations are

$$ \frac{d^2x^\lambda }{dt^2} + \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu }\frac{dx^\mu }{dt}\frac{dx^\nu }{dt} = 0,$$

where $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu} $

but i would be itnerested in euler lagrange equation for a surface minimizing area i mean we mnimize the Area instead of the lenght

what would be then the equations ?? the are is te area of the surface with a metric $ g_{a,b} $

$$ dA(g_{a,b} ,\sigma ) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(M, g)$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold and $U \subset \mathbb R^k$ be an small open set, where $1\le k<n$. Let $F: U \to M$ be an immersion. Then one can calculate the area

$$A(F) = \int_U dA,$$
where $dA$ is the area element, locally given by 
$$dA = \sqrt{\det (g(\partial_i F, \partial _j F))}  \mathrm dx^1 \cdots \mathrm dx^k.$$

when $k=1$, we have $dA = \sqrt{g(\dot x, \dot x)} dx$, so this is the generalization for the case of geodesic.

One can, as in the $k=1$ case, calculate the Euler-Lagrange equation of this area functioncal. The critical point will be a minimal surface, that is an immersion so that the mean curvautre vector 
$$\vec H = \text{tr} A = \sum_{i, j=1}^k g^{ij}A_{ij}$$
vanishes.